# How to find out whether Method has called for given instance. Like "Object obj" check whether obj called "equals" method or not

Tags: java, object, methods

I want to find out whether method for some object is being called for that instance or not.

Is it possible in java ?

Like ...

```
class Button {
 public void focus(){}
 public void setName(){}
}

class MyTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Button button = new Button();
    button.focus();

    // I want to find out on button instance whether focus() or setName() is called or not.
    whetherMethodCalled(button);
    // OR
    whetherMethodCalled(button, 'focus');
    whetherMethodCalled(button, 'setName');
  }
}
```

**EDIT** : Forgot to add Button class is third party class which I cannot modify...  Also I want to check in my code whether method has called for given object instance or not on basis of that I have to write some code.

Comment: Use a debugger?  Add print statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reduce extra work, perhaps profiling your application with JConsole or another tool is good enough to show if certain methods have run. Another option is using a code coverage tool like EMMA which detects dead code. There is a list of open-source profilers for Java at http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers and EMMA is at http://emma.sourceforge.net/.

With some extra work AspectJ could be use to intercept method calls without changing existing code. For example, the following would intercept calls to Button.focus()

```
@Aspect
public class InterceptButtonMethods {
  @Before("execution(* Button.focus())")
  public void beforeInvoke() {
    System.out.println("Button.focus invoked");
    incrementFocusCount();
  }
}
```

If more extra work is ok, there is a way to wrap all calls to the Button's focus() and setName() methods so that they update separate counters in addition to their normal functions. This can be done by extending Button in YourButton class which is identical to Button except for a couple of int counters with getters, setters and increment methods; and countingFocus() and countingSetName() methods which update their counters and call focus() and setName() respectively, such as in outline:

```
Class YourButton extends Button { 
  int focusCount; 
  int setNameCount
  int getFocusCount() {return this.focusCount;}
  void setFocusCount(int counter) {this.focusCount = counter} // optional to reset counter
  void incrementFocusCount() {this.focusCount = getFocusCount() + 1;)
  ...
  void countingFocus() {
    incrementFocusCount();
    focus()
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the button and verify in your `MyTest` how many times the method must be called. Using [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) you can mock and stub your [methods](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12)(Stubbing voids requires different approach from when(Object) because the compiler does not like void methods inside brackets) and then verify it using `verify` statement.

```
verify(mockButton, times(1)).focus();
verify(mockButton, times(1)).setName();
```

Comment: I cannot modify Button class.

Answer (score 0):

If it is required in many places and involves complex things, I recommend to use Mockito to test your code. Using that you can verify if the method was invoked (also how many times if invoked)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper class over the 3rd party Button class through which all calls to Button class will be made.
This wrapper class can keep track of whether each method has been called or not

```
class ButtonCaller {

    private Button button = null;
    private boolean focusCalled;
    private boolean setNameCalled;

    public ButtonCaller() {
        button = new Button();
        focusCalled = false;
        setNameCalled = false;
    }

    public void focus() {
        button.focus();
        focusCalled = true;
    }

    public void setName() {
        button.setName();
        setNameCalled = true;
    }

    public void whetherMethodCalled(ButtonMethod method) {
        switch (method) {
        case FOCUS:
            return focusCalled;
        case SET_NAME:
            return setNameCalled;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown ButtonMethod !!!");
    }

    public static Enum ButtonMethod {
        FOCUS,
        SET_NAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good solution but I have 50 class and few Interface to modify so this won't help ... anyway thanks for the solution.